# How to fill json array items in arraylist in adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview, baseadapter

I am parsing a JSON and display it in a `Recyclerview`. Now what I am trying is I want to get all the `Headertext` of my JSON data and fill it into array list and pass that array list to another fragment.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BuyerMemberValueAddedAdapter.SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    BuyerMemberShipValueAddedModel mservicebenefits = new BuyerMemberShipValueAddedModel();
    final ArrayList<BuyerMemberShipValueAddedModel> serviceinfobenefitList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int item = 0; item < serviceinfobenefitList.size(); item++) {
        mservicebenefits.setValueAddedService_Headertxt(imagesList.get(position).getValueAddedService_Headertxt());
    }
    serviceinfobenefitList.addAll(Collections.singleton(mservicebenefits));
    System.out.println("Service Texts"+serviceinfobenefitList.size());



    holder.btngetstarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("servicelist", serviceinfobenefitList);
            //set Fragmentclass Arguments
            SubmitOurValueAddedService fragobj = new SubmitOurValueAddedService();
            fragobj.setArguments(args);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = currentFragment.getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_home_fl_container, fragobj);
            fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit youre code like this:

```
for(int item = 0; item<serviceinfobenefitList.size(); item++)
{
    mservicebenefits.setValueAddedService_Headertxt(imagesList.get(position).getValueAddedService_Headertxt());
    serviceinfobenefitList.addAll(Collections.singleton(mservicebenefits));
}
```

Here's how to get the list:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
BuyerMemberShipValueAddedModel buyerMemberShipValueAddedModel= (BuyerMemberShipValueAddedModel) bundle.getSerializable("servicelist");
```

Youre BuyerMemberShipValueAddedModel Model Must implements by Serializable

Comment: thanks for answer but i am not able to fill arraylist ,